# Problems parsing json String to objects in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I googled a lot, pretty much copied code i found online from tutorials to simply parse a json String in Swift to useable objects.

Code:

```
func parseJson(json: String) -> [AnyObject] {
    let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    do {
        if let array = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [AnyObject] {
                return array
            }
    }
    catch {
        // Error hanndling here
    }

    return [AnyObject]()
}
```

Json String im trying to parse:

```
"response":{"loggedIn":false,"message":"Some errormessage here"}}
```

What happens: 
The program won't jump into the if let array = ... It stops there since it can't parse the string to json (or AnyObject) and will simply go to return AnyObject.

Why does this happen and how do i fix it?

Comment: Your JSON is a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code a little to allow for better debugging:

```
func parseJson(json: String) -> [AnyObject] {
    let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    do {
        let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        if let array = parsed as? [AnyObject] {
                return array
            }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return [AnyObject]()
}
```

Two changes there:

1. Printing any error caught.
2. Doing `JSONObjectWithData` and the `as?` conversion in two separate steps.

Pasting this in a playground quickly reveals an error being caught: "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." Your JSON fragment is missing the opening `{`.

Once that problem is fixed, you’ll see that `parsed` gets set, but the subsequent `if let array = parsed as? [AnyObject]` falls through. That’s because your top-level element is a dictionary, not an array, so casting to `[AnyObject]` fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Im completely new to Swift

Comment: Welcome to Swift! You'll find Swift's type strictness interacts badly with the open structure of JSON. Instead of using lots of "as" casts in your code, I recommend investigating SwiftyJSON and some of the other libraries for working with JSON in Swift.